# iOS: get video duration and thumbnails without playing video

Tags: ios, ios6

I need to get a (local) video's duration, and then get access to its individual frames as `UIImage`s. So far I've been using `MPMoviePlayerController` for this.

First I register for `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification` events, and then call `prepareToPlay`. When the event is received I note the video's duration, and then I request frames via `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes`.

This works, however the video seems to start playing even if I have not added the it to the view in any way (I can hear the audio playing in the background).

Is there any way to get a video's duration and frames without actually playing the video?

Comment: If you are storing your video in the filesystem then you can access it as an [AVAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) assetWithUrl: and the returned AVAsset has a duration property. Not sure about the thumbnails though.

Comment: Any suggestions on this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617130/error-getting-same-video-thumbnail-image-every-time-in-swift3-ios/47617794#47617794

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To get the duration:

```
NSURL *sourceMovieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:somePath];
AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:sourceMovieURL options:nil];
CMTime duration = sourceAsset.duration;
```

To get a framegrab:

```
AVAssetImageGenerator* generator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:destinationAsset];

//Get the 1st frame 3 seconds in
int frameTimeStart = 3;
int frameLocation = 1;

//Snatch a frame
CGImageRef frameRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(frameTimeStart,frameLocation) actualTime:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: This does indeed get the duration properly, thank you. However the "grab a frame" timing seems to be a little off. I had to use CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(offsetInSeconds, 600).

Comment: What is frameTime? I see frameTimeStart, is that supposed to be frameTime?

Answer (score 11):

You can get in **swift** like this

```
func getMediaDuration(url: NSURL!) -> Float64{
    let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url) as AVURLAsset
    let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
    return CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
}
```

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617130/error-getting-same-video-thumbnail-image-every-time-in-swift3-ios

Comment: `func getMediaDuration(url: URL) -> Double {
        let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url) as AVURLAsset
        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    }`

Answer (score 6):

Calling `setShouldAutoPlay:NO` does the trick with MPMoviePlayerController:

```
 moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
[moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];   
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
```

Edit: I'm getting downvoted without explanation, but I'll stand by this answer. If you need to use `MPMoviePlayerController` then this will prevent autoplay of the media, yet still allow you to get duration and thumbnails as per my original question.

Comment: Does anyone else agree that it's kind of silly to have autoplay set to TRUE as a default?

Comment: Your answer does indeed, uh, answer the question; but I would guess you're being down voted because what you're doing with `MPMoviePlayerController` is an ugly workaround that possibly uses more resources than needed to get the information you want, and may break in future iOS releases. You're asking the system to load to memory and prepare to play the video when all you need is some metadata about it.

Off topic: just out of curiosity, does it show you who down voted you? I've never been down voted so I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
class func getVideoInfo(from url: URL,
                        completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?, _ duration: CGFloat?) -> Void)) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        let avAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        avAssetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let thumnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
        do {
            let cgThumbImage = try avAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumnailTime, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbNailImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgThumbImage)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(thumbNailImage, duration)
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```