# Create thumbnail from video ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got thumbnail from video in photo library, now I want add duration and camera icon on the thumbnail like image . Have any suggestion? thanks.

[image: thumbnailImg]

Answer (score 4):

You can get duration of vide while you are selecting video file from Library like this:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    AVPlayerItem *SelectedItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:selectedVideoUrl];

    CMTime duration = SelectedItem.duration;
    float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
    NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
}
```

And you can get thumb of Video using :-

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbNail:(NSString*)stringPath
{

//stringPath is a path of stored video file from document directory
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    //Player autoplays audio on init
    [player stop];

    return thumbnail;
}
```

now you have both you just need to create you custom view and do what you want.

Do Not forget to add

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>
```

Here also one nice answer that suitable
 with your issue Please check Bellow:-

[iOS: get video duration and thumbnails without playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742262/ios-get-video-duration-and-thumbnails-without-playing-video)